# MVVM update view model when model changes

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I need to update ViewModel, when Model changes and Model, when ViewModel changes. In my case, I have: **ProjectViewModel** implementing **INotifyPropertyChanged** and **Project**(model) implementing **INotifyPropertyChanged**. When ViewModel changes I simply change Model directly. But when Model changes, then what? I tried to handle Model's property changed event in ViewModel. But then I will have strong reference from long-live Model and that will cause memory leak, or not? If yes so how to do it otherwise?

EDIT:

```
class ProjectViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Project Project;

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return Project.Name;
        }
        set
        {
            Project.Name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    public ProjectViewModel(Project project)
    {
        this.Project = project;
        project.PropertyChanged += OnProjectChanged;
    }

    private void OnProjectChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == "Name")
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    } //and then things for UI....
}
class Project : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set
        {
            name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }//and then logic (for saving)
}
```

EDIT2: Or can I implement something like IDisposable in ViewModel? Or make model(Project) property in ViewModel public and bind to it directly?

Comment: Please add code you have, it will be easier to figure out

Comment: Causing a memory leak is hard to say, but the object and its references will not be garbage collected if it is still referenced. I would reconsider your approach: if a ViewModel lives as long as the Model it represents, is its purpose purely to be a slimmed down model for UI purposes? In that case, (a) would the Model suffice or (b) isn't there a point where your ViewModel get mapped back onto your Model - which then acts as a DTO?

Comment: @Gigabyte I need view model because in future it will contain ui related things (support for renaming, etc.) I have it for UI. And model can be updated from other objects. It will contain logic for saving and maybe more things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I would do what you suggested in your second edit, implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` on the Model, making `Project` a public property, and binding to `Project.Name` directly.

Answer (score 1):

If your VM depends in any way on the value of a property in the model then yes, you will need to subscribe to its [INPC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) notifications. But the reality is that usually the VM doesn't need to know about specific model values unless it is aggregating the values (i.e. summing a value from a list of objects).

When you do need to subscribe to the model's INPC then you'll also need to unsubscribe. This is not as troublesome as it might seem because the VM triggers the fetching or refetching of the models so it is clear when the unsubscribing needs to be done. Check the [INotifyCollectionChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) interface - this is a good place to start for the subscribing and unsubscribing.